# Disk Partitioning on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, partition

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a partioned volume and if it even makes sense to do that on an Amazon EC2 server.

I have a standard Ubuntu server and I'd like to separate the /home and /tmp folders.

My main goal is to add user quotas to the /home folder and disable the special permissions in /tmp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Ubuntu server on EC2 is essentially the same as an Ubuntu server anywhere else. Yes, you can partition, in the exact same way you would on any other Ubuntu install, and yes, it makes sense for all the same reasons.

People seem to think EC2 is something magical and different, but it's fundamentally Amazon giving you an Ubuntu VM. Don't overthink it!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Okay, but how can I do that ? Since Amazon gives me a volume with everything in one single partition. Should I create new volumes and attach to the server ? is there a way to add partitions to an existing root volume with the OS already installed ?

Comment: I'd go with the new volume approach, personally.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Yeah, that can be painful to manage, I'll be creating more than 40 servers, that way I'll have 3x more disks to manage (Snapshots, Backup restore and so on). Probably having a NFS server with a shared /home folder is the ideal solution for me.

Comment: @Erico If you're making 40 servers, **get a configuration management system to handle this for you**. Take a look at things like Ansible.

Comment: +1 for Ansible. It'll take you twice as long the first time around as you're learning the tool, but after that, you'll be able to deploy (and keep updated) those 40 (or 1000) servers in 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll definitely take a look at these tools.

Answer (score 3):

It makes more sense to add new EBS volumes, and mount them in the locations you want as opposed to partitioning a small root drive. Remember that the ephemeral storage you get (/mnt) is ephemeral, meaning it is not persistent if there is a reboot for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3):

A root volume in Amazon EC2 is not the same as a root volume anywhere else, so assuming that you can manipulate it in the same way as a root volume on server in a rack in your Comms Room will get you into trouble

If you want to separate volumes in your server instance, add an EBS volume to it, create a partition on it using fdisk, create a file system on it using mkfs.ext4, then mount it on whatever mount point you wish.

If you want this to persist through reboots, update the /etc/fstab file so that the volume is mounted at boot.